# SQL Server query to ORACLE linq server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server configured for ORACLE link server

[image]

Whenever I execute the first query, it works fine, but not the second one.

How to execute the second query?

Is it possible to query without OpenQuery?

Comment: You need few more **single quotes** before and after `akash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link useful [link](http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Use-Parameters-with-OPENQUERY-in-SQL.aspx)

```
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(500);
set @Query='select  *  from table where name Like '+''''+'%akash%'+'''';
print @Query;
EXEC(@Query) AT ORCL
```

actually ''''(4  quotes) solved my problem